# image doesn't stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I was given [this design](http://festivals.ie:8080/festivals/) that I'm trying to apply to [my website](http://festivals.ie/). Notice that the `<html>` element has a background image (hands in the air), that sticks to the bottom of the page.

However, when I migrated the css files over to my application, for some reason this image appears halfway down the page instead. I've checked the relevant CSS and in both cases it's:

```
html {
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("../../img/bg.svg");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    outline: 0 none !important;
}
```

so why does the image stick to the bottom of the page [here](http://festivals.ie:8080/festivals/), but appear halfway down the page [here](http://festivals.ie/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the computed height of the 1st link is set such that the image is at the bottom, whereas for the link where the image appears part way down the computed height is much lower.
`height: 170px;` compared to `height: 2006px;`

<strike>I'm not sure what's setting the height for you, but sorting that out will solve your image problem</strike>

Edit:
Actually it seems to be in this rule which is only on one of those sites:

```
media="screen, projection"
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `height: 100%` set for your `html` and `body`. This is normally done to able to have full-height elements. But in this case, this is proving to be the cause of the issue. Removing this it fix the issue.

Check in Firebug or Chrome Inspector and you will see some thing like:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Remove it. OR Override it from your style sheet.

Answer (score 3):

It's not working on the 2nd site due to the `body { height: 100% }` styling.

static/bundle-bundle_responsive_head.css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's actually the background image on the body tag that is not sticking to the bottom.  Turning off the `height: 100%` body rule in bundle-bundle-responsive-head.css fixes it, though I'm not sure how that will affect other things on the site.

I found this by using the DOM inspector in Chrome and turning on/off the rules for the various elements to see what effect they would have.